# Wordpress bool(false) means taxonomy compare not working

Tags: taxonomy

I have a loop pulling in a wordpress content page  'peopleformat'.

Here is that loop

```
<?php

                // Start the Loop.
                while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
                $do_not_duplicate[] = $post->ID;

                    /*
                     * Include the post format-specific template for the content. If you want to
                     * use this in a child theme, then include a file called called content-___.php
                     * (where ___ is the post format) and that will be used instead.
                     */
                get_template_part( 'content', 'peopleformat' );

                ?>

                <!--Get all the rest of the posts to display  -->
                <?php endwhile; ?>
                <?php
                // 2nd loop

            $args = array( 'post_type' => 'profile', 'posts_per_page' => 300, 'order' => 'DESC' );
            $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
            while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
            if (in_array($post->ID, $do_not_duplicate)) continue;

                ?>
```

Within the people format page I am comparing two variables. If they are the same then ' do something'

```
<?php 
            $acf_tax = get_field('key_person');
            $custom_tax = get_taxonomy( $Team );
            if($acf_tax === $custom_tax) :
        ?>
```

However after doing a var_dump( $acf_tax, $custom_tax ), it comes up with bool(false) bool(false) . And im not sure how to stop from being a bool? And finding the values properly?

The end goal i would like to achieve is if acf_tax and custom_tax have the same value then it will 'do something'.

Comment: Sorry I thought because it had been placed on hold, it wouldnt be able to accept answers.

Comment: That's right, but moderators will be happy to remove the `[on hold]` mark if you will improve it and make it fit the site's scope better. FIY: "If a question is edited by the original poster when it is marked on hold, it will automatically be placed in a review queue to be considered for reopening." see [help > closed questions](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions)